# How do you test soil for the nutrients present in it?

Tags: ecology, methods, soil, bioinorganic-chemistry

I recently noticed that my rose garden has been in a very terrible state. The roses keep dying. I tested the soil for its pH and that was fine. 
Now I'm wondering how would I carry out a test to see what specific nutrients I should use to get my soil better.

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate here: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should go to [Gardening.SE](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Send soil samples to a soil lab (e.g., [here](https://www.blinc.com/soils.htm)). 
They will likely use the [Mehlich III extractant](http://aesl.ces.uga.edu/protected/methods/details/stl-soil/or4.html)   method to extract and quantify the nutrients (most importantly the bases such as  Ca, Mg, K, and Na). Will cost less than $25.

Comment: was the pH level from 6.0 to 7.4 ? because that is what plant life needs to dissolve nutrients easily